# Slack Modal and AWS Lambda: Returning response_action after wrong user input throws an error in modal

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, slack-api

I´m currently building an Slack app with a modal. I´m using a serverless AWS Stack containing a Lambda function that handles the user interactions. Those interactions are verified in that Lambda.

If the user input is correct, the modal is closed successfully (Lambda returns a 200 response). However, if I return the following as the body when user input is wrong and user submits the modal ([as per Slack´s documentation](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#displaying_errors)):

```
{
"response_action" : "errors",
"errors": {
    "startDate": "Start date is incorrect.",
    },
}
```

The full response I'm returning at the end of the Lambda function is:

```
response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            response_action : "errors",
            errors: {
                "endDate": "Start date is incorrect.",
            }
        })
    };
```

I receive the error in the next screenshot:

[image]

Am I missing something? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found the problem and here´s the solution in my case (might be helpful to you reader):

### The right block type

The modal I built is made of interactive components, like a date picker. These components are blocks of type "section". For better comprehension, they look like this:

[image: Section type block]

However, it seems that´s not compatible with the the feature to display input errors. For that, you have to choose blocks of type "input". Again, for understanding, they look like this:

[image: Input type block]

And that type of block **is** compatible with [displaying error messages as per Slack documentation](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#displaying_errors).

### The response from AWS Lambda

When you validate a user input, in the AWS Lambda function, [Slack expects](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#displaying_errors) you to return the following structure in the response if you want to warn about an error:

```
{ "response_action": "errors", "errors": { "ticket-due-date": "You may not select a due date in the past" } }
```

However, it looks like you need to indicate the time of content by adding a header defining content is of JSON type without a statusCode. In my case, response that works is:

```
response = {
        headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
        response_action : "errors",
        errors: {
            "test": "That date is invalid. Please, select a future date.",
        }
    })
```

And that way, the custom error message appears:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I was facing the very same issue.

Comment: You're welcome.